# HTML/CSS help: Why is my absolutely positioned displaying outside of its parent div

Tags: html, css

I am doing some practice with relative and absolute positioning and I can't seem to figure out why this code is behaving this way

For some reason my absolutely positioned div containing a

tag is causing the element to go outside of it's parent container specifically when the left property is set to 100%. At 99% it is staying inside, but using 100% seems to push it outside. 0% also works as expected. Can someone explain to me why setting this property to 100% causes it to go outside of the boundaries of the div? Is there a way to fix this?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer-div {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
}

.p-tag {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: pink;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

.inner-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 79%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.super-inner-div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.no-margin {
  margin: 0;
}

.left {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
  <p class="p-tag no-margin"> This is the name</p>
  <div class="inner-div">
    <div class="super-inner-div left">
      <p class="no-margin">•</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: left:100% --> 100% of the parent width from the left --> you end outside (use right:0)

Comment: To stay inside don't use percentages, use px or em units. Absolute positioning takes the element outside the document flow relative to the next relative position element above it.